# Lotusscript function FileLen returns negative long for files over 2 GB

Tags: lotusscript, lotus-notes

I want to check the size of the file(s) the user selects using the OpenFileDialog in IBM Domino designer.
For this I am calling the function FileLen. This works fine with normal files. But with a big file (over 2 GB), I always get a negative long returned.
Is there a way to get the correct size of such big files?
The problem is reported on the web, but no solution was suggested!
I started with the following code (Got it from [this blog](http://maheshwaranthiru.blogspot.de/2011/11/lotus-script-function-for-retreiving.html)):

```
    On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    Dim pathName As String, fileName As String
    Dim verLen As Long
    pathName$ = "C:\Users\Maheshwaran Thirumoo\Desktop\test\*.*"
    fileName$ = Dir$(pathName$)

    Do While fileName$ <> ""
            verLen = Filelen("C:\Users\Maheshwaran Thirumoo\Desktop\test\" +fileName$)
            Print  + "====="& fileName$  "====" & verLen
            fileName$ = Dir$()
    Loop
    Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
    Print "Error @ line # : " & Cstr(Erl) & "<br> Error is : " & Error
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileLen` returns a long data type. This can be a value from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

So with that command you won't be able to do it. LotusScript is quite an old language and still based on 32bit systems (late 90's).

You could use LS2J to have Java get the file size and pass it back to LotusScript, but you may hit other limitations on variable sizes.

Here is an example I did that works:

1. Created a Java class as follows.

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileSizeHelper {

    public static String getFileSize(String filename) { 

        File file = new File(filename);
        return "" + file.length();

    }
}
```

2. Create a directory c:\notes\test and put the FileSizeHelper.class file into it.

3. Edit the Notes.ini and add the following line.

```
JavaUserClasses=c:\notes\test
```

4. Restart your Notes client. Open designer and create a LotusScript agent as follows:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

UseLSX "*javacon"
Sub Initialize

    dim mySession as New JavaSession()
    Dim myClass As Variant
    Dim myObject As variant
    Dim answer As String

    Set myClass = mySession.Getclass("FileSizeHelper")
    Set myObject = myClass.createObject

    answer = myClass.getFileSize("<PUT FILENAME HERE>")

    MsgBox answer

End Sub
```

5. Change `<PUT FILENAME HERE>` to the path to the file you want to get the file size off. It will follow the Java convention on referencing a file. e.g. "C:\\temp\\test.txt", "/temp/test.txt".

When you run it, it should show a string of the file size.

Answer (score 2):

In LotusScript the range for Long is between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647. That is 2 GB in Bytes.

There is a workaround to get the length for files <4GB, files bigger than that can not be measured with Filelen. The workaround (taken from [this german site](http://www.vbarchiv.net/tipps/tipp_886-dateigroesse-fuer-dateien-groesser-als-2gb-ermitteln.html) would be:

```
Public Function FileSize(ByVal sFile As String) As Currency
  ' Get size of file, 
  ' Works until size of 4GB
  Dim nSize As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  If Dir$(sFile) <> "" Then
    nSize = FileLen(sFile)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' Error: Possible size > 4GB
      FileSize = 2147483648# + 2147483648#
    Else
      If nSize < 0 Then
    ' File is larger than 2GB!
        FileSize = 2147483648# + (2147483648# - Abs(nSize))
      Else
        FileSize = nSize
      End If
    End If
  Else
    ' If file not found
    ' give back -1 as value
    FileSize = -1
  End If
  On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

Unfortunately I do not know -and could not find- a method to go over 4GB...

Answer (score 0):

FileLen() in LotusScript also lacks the Support of non-LMBCS characters in file names. This raises "File not found exception" error message.

Circumventing the 4 GB size limit plus non-Unicode support requires to resort to either LS2J or COM/OLE classes. This sample File wrapper LotusScript class fits these cases:

```vb
Dim f As New File( filename ) ' « Scripting.FileSystemObject.File »
Msgbox ( f.Size )

Private Class File ' « Scripting.FileSystemObject.File »
   Private fso As Variant
   Private this As Variant
   Sub New ( fileName As String )' File constructor
try: On Error GoTo catch
       Set fso = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
       Set this = fso.getFile( filename )
       GoTo finally
catch: Select Case Err
       Case Else
           Me.throw "Unexpected exception"
       End Select
finally: ' A place to release held resources    
    End Sub ' Constructor
    Public Property Get Size As Currency
        Me.Size = this.Size ' Variant to Currency
    End Property ' Size
    Private Sub throw( Text As String )
        Error Err, TypeName(Me) &" - "& LSI_Info(12) &" - "& Text &|
    | & "Error" & Str(Err) &" "& Error$
    End Sub ' Exception thrower
End Class ' « Scripting.FileSystemObject.File »
```

Comment: So what is the question?